# Microsoft Teams send Activity Feed Notification through Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a with yeoman teams scaffolded tab in which I ask for adminconsent for application permission.
On a Go backend I then use the code to retrieve the access token. I am also getting all Users of the team.
Although I am using only application permissions, I can not send notifications to the admin account. When trying to send notifications to other accounts, the Graph API returns a 204 Status Code but the activity feed of the recipient stays empty.

The application has following application permissions (with granted admin consent):

- ChannelMember.ReadAll
- GroupMember.ReadAll
- Team.ReadBasic.All
- TeamMember.Read.All
- TeamsActivity.Send

This is the Manifest file with version 1.11:

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
  "version": "{{VERSION}}",
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
    "resource": "api://{{DOMAIN}}.{{APPLICATION_ID}}"
  },
  "devicePermissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "activities": {
    "activityTypes": [
      {
        "type": "newActivity",
        "description": "A new Activity Description"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The HTTP POST request to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamID}/sendNotification`

The JSON Body:

```
{
    "topic": {
        "source": "entityUrl",
        "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%s"
    },
    "activityType": "newActivity",
    "previewText": {
        "content": "A new Activity Description"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "odata.type": "microsoft.graph.aadUserNotificationRecipient",
        "userId": "{{USER_ID}}"
    }
}
```

The recipient is also Member of the channel the activity is referring to. I also made sure that the recipient can receive notifications.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#:~:text=%20The%20following%20are%20the%20requirements%20for%20sending,they%20are%20part%20of.%20For%20more...%20More%20
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT thank you for the provided Link. In the meantime I changed my code and request a bit with which I can send out notifications successfully. However, even though I checked my project against your doc, the notifications can still not be send to the admin and are displayed as sent by the admin.

Comment: Have you confirm once you have done Requirements for using the activity feed notification APIs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#requirements-for-using-the-activity-feed-notification-apis

Comment: Looked at it again and I can confirm that I've done the requirements. It looks like it uses delegated permission since I get an error that the receiver can not be the sender of the activity, however I never added delegated permissions in Azure AD, only application permissions

Comment: as per you mention above error , it looks like your receiver and sender  are same.
You might get an error if multiple Teams apps in the same scope (team, chat or user) are using the same Azure AD app. Make sure that you're using unique Azure AD apps.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?

Comment: The issue is inconsistent. It is a problem with Azure or the Graph API. Old Notifications I have sent are visible after a delay of 5-7 days. New Notifications are now displayed near instantly.